# Passar dados HTML para PDF preenchivel

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Fala galera, to com um problemão aqui pra vocês me ajudarem.

Tenho um PDF preenchivel (com campos que posso preencher) e tenho tambem um formulário em HTML. O que preciso fazer é pegar os valores dos inputs e mandar para esse template em PDF preenchendo nos campos adequados.

O problema é que não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Já pesquisei na internet e nada.

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha sobre XML, talvez isso possa te ajudar a transformar esses dados em um formulário organizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Sallazar, tudo bem?!

Eu já utilizei duas formas para editar PDF's.

Uma delas é editar no próprio front-end utilizando as bibliotecas [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) e/ou [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), ambas são *javascript*.

O **html2canvas** é usado para converter todo o conteúdo HTML - que pode estar estilizado - em uma imagem.
O **jsPDF** é responsável por gerar o PDF.

Eu utilizei as duas bibliotecas porque possuía um imagem PNG resultado de uma conversão PDF -> PNG; Defini essa imagem como background do meu body e fiz todas as edições necessárias via HTML e CSS. Após isso, converti todo meu conteúdo HTML estilizado pelo CSS em uma imagem através do html2canvas e então manipulei o resultado com o jsPDF para gerar o PDF. Por ser um PDF gerado a partir de uma imagem, o arquivo final ficou bem grande (*>=5Mb*);

A outra forma é utilizar o [ZendPdf](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zendpdf.create.html) para carregar o seu PDF e fazer as edições com o PHP e a biblioteca. Desta maneira você consegue criar e editar o PDF, mantendo o texto em formato de texto e o arquivo ganha alguns kbytes em relação ao template.

Existem bastante tutorial na internet para as duas formas. Eu recomendo utilizar o ZendPdf.

Comment: Massa, vou dar uma olhada nesse ZendPdf. Agora, estou usando JSP no projeto e não PHP, da pra fazer?

Comment: Com o JSP você pode utilizar o jsPDF mas entra no caso que mencionei acima. Você precisará converter seu PDF em uma imagem, defini-la como `background-image` de todo o conteúdo que deseja exibir no pdf e fazer as alterações.

Comment: Eu pesquisei sobre criação de PDF's em java e achei essa solução: https://www.baeldung.com/java-pdf-creation

Comment: Caso eu tenha sanado sua dúvida e realmente ter te ajudado, vote como melhor resposta para que a pergunta seja fechada xD **Abraços Sallazar**!!!